# Select deselect the radio in uitableview section with array in ios swift

Tags: swift, radio-button, tableview, sections

In tableview have different section.

Want to add the radio button for all the section.

Each section have individual select and deselect in tableview.

In first section choice1,[show in fig]

Selected cheese means cheese want to select, next if user click bacon means cheese automatically deselect.

[Here using radio button SSRadioButton class for click action. Create a radio button in tableview cell. how to write the button action for radio button. or suggest any new way].

Each radio button want individual select and deselect. The same process for all the section in tableview. how is possible help me. Thanks advance.[image]

my code:

```
 var radioControllerChoice : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()
    var radioControllerDip : SSRadioButtonsController = SSRadioButtonsController()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return table_data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return table_data[section].menu_id.count
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:CustomiseTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Customise") as! CustomiseTableViewCell
        cell.name.text?=table_data[indexPath.section].menu_name[indexPath.row]
        print(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row])

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 2:
            radioControllerChoice.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
            radioControllerChoice.shouldLetDeSelect = false
        case 3:
            radioControllerDip.addButton(cell.radioBtn)
            radioControllerDip.shouldLetDeSelect = false

            switch Int(table_data[indexPath.section].customize[indexPath.row]) {
            case 1:
                cell.radioBtn.isHidden = false
            default:
                print("Invalid choose")


                cell.radioBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.didSelectButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.radioBtn.tag = indexPath.row

            }
        }
    }

func didSelectButton(selectedButton: UIButton?)
{
        /// need solution for button action help me..
}
```

Comment: It would be good to include relevant parts of the code like `cellForRow` and `didSelectRow` methods and your data source so we can help you fix your problem

Comment: can you share any code to fix this problem.. i am struggling..

Comment: I can give a generic answer which may or may not help you but if you update your question with the code I can probably help you overcome the problem

Comment: update my question check it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use UIButton instead of SSRadioButton, and then you can change the image of button for checked and unchecked radio button.

**Swift3.2:**
CustomiseTableViewCell

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didToggleRadioButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CustomiseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIButton!
var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?

func initCellItem() {

    let deselectedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_radio_button_unchecked_white")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "ic_radio_button_checked_white")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    radioButton.setImage(deselectedImage, for: .normal)
    radioButton.setImage(selectedImage, for: .selected)
    radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.radioButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {
    print("radio button tapped")
    let isSelected = !self.radioButton.isSelected
    self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
    if isSelected {
        deselectOtherButton()
    }
    let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
    delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(tappedCellIndexPath)
}

func deselectOtherButton() {
    let tableView = self.superview?.superview as! UITableView
    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
    for indexPath in indexPaths! {
        if indexPath.row != tappedCellIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == tappedCellIndexPath.section {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)) as! CustomiseTableViewCell
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }
}

}
```

Call *initCellItem* method from UITableViewDataSource's delegate method:

```
// Your ViewController

let menuList = [ ["Cheese", "Bacon", "Egg"],
["Fanta", "Lift", "Coke"] ]  // Inside your ViewController
var selectedElement = [Int : String]()

func didToggleRadioButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let section = indexPath.section
    let data = menuList[section][indexPath.row]
    if let previousItem = selectedElement[section] {
        if previousItem == data {
            selectedElement.removeValue(forKey: section)
            return
        }
    }
    selectedElement.updateValue(data, forKey: section)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
   let cell:CustomiseTableViewCell = 
   tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Customise") as! CustomiseTableViewCell
    let item = menuList[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.itemLabel.text = item
    if item == selectedElement[indexPath.section] {
        cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
    }
    cell.initCellItem()
    cell.delegate = self
    // Your logic....
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Selected cheese means cheese want to select, next if user click bacon means cheese automatically deselect. Each radio button want individual select and deselect. The same process for all the section in tableview. how is possible help me... how to write logic in cellforrow.

Comment: @saravanar, I have edited the above code to address your problem. Now it's working, Please check it.

Comment: how to add the elements[cheese,egg][fanta,lift] in array when select and deselect the radio button..

Comment: on radioButtonTap action you can get the indexPath of that that cell instance and and add element as: yourArray.append(menuList[tappedCellIndexPath.section][tappedCellIndexPath.row])

Comment: in  radioButtonTap how can i call that  menuList array. that array declare in viewcontroller, how can i call that array CustomiseTableViewCell..

Comment: ru get my question.. in radioButtonTap how can i call that menuList array. that array declare in viewcontroller, how can i call that array CustomiseTableViewCell

Comment: yeah, i got it. Create a CustomTableViewCellDelegate protocol with method didToggleRadioButton in CustomiseTableViewCell.swift file. and create a delegate property var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate? in your customCell class. call the didToggleRadioButton method on button action by passing tappedCellIndexPath.

Comment: You need to implement the didToggleRadioButton method in your viewcontroller when you adopt the CustomTableViewCellDelegate protocol. In cellForRowAtindexPath of your viewController, set the cell's property delegate to self.

Comment: @saravanar, you should vote an answer, if it's working.

Comment: how to combine the section values, that means each section selected array values

Comment: how to use dictionary for add the values in each section.

Comment: Inside didToggleRadioButton method you can update the value as: selectedElement.updateValue("yourValue", forKey: "yourSection")

Comment: @RahulKumar thank you for this valuable answer, I followed the same instructions but I got an error when pressing on the button which is (Could not cast value of type 'UIViewControllerWrapperView' () to 'UITableView')

Comment: can you share your block of code that is causing the error, after button press?

Comment: I have changed the code (let tableView = self.superview?.superview as! UITableView ) to ( let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView) and it works but I didn't know why?
I have a UITableViewController, maybe for this reason? @RahulKumar

Comment: which swift version you are using?

Comment: Actually in swift3.0, _self.superview as! UITableView_ was giving me _UITableViewWrapperView_ so i used _self.superview?.superview as! UITableView_  which was working. For your code you can use **let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView**

Comment: @RahulKumar I have tried the same, but while scrolling radio button selection changing. Any idea?

Comment: @Fatima Any idea about selection change on scrolling?

Comment: @Mac_Play It uses the existing cell instance to show other rows while scrolling the table, and it doesn't reset button state to normal for other row representing new data; so you need to store the indexPath of selected items and based on that set the image of button for selected state. It can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Can you please share some example to understand, it would be great.

Comment: In my case menuList is array of dicitionary. it's throwing some error.

Comment: Then you need to update the code to access the menuList items

Comment: Yes. So selectedElement also should be an array of dictionary right?

Comment: There is no need for that, simple array would work. It's your call btw, how you want to implement

Comment: var qaArray = [[String:Any]]() this array contains my data to display in tableview(both section and row).   In my cellforrow         var ansDetailArray: [[String:String]] =  (qaArray[indexPath.section]["data"]) as! [[String:String]]
 cell.lblTitle!.text = String(describing: ansDetailArray[indexPath.row]["s_answer"]!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456084/uibutton-state-changing-while-scrolling-the-tableview-with-multiple-sections-s/51456106?noredirect=1#comment89882001_51456106

Comment: Please check my question in the above comment.

Comment: How to use same code in didselect method of tableview for implement check and uncheck on complete cell of tableview

Comment: What i understood, you are saying on click of cell, checkbox should be checked/unchecked the same way right?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate way:**

You can use simple `UIButton` instead of any third party library (`SSRadioButton`) and use it like:

1. Set the `UIButton's` `image` in `default state` to - **circle** (as in the screenshot)
2. Set the `UIButton's` `image` in `selected state` to - **filled circle**

`UIButton's` `action event` can be captured in a normal way like you do in any other case.

Something like this:

[image]

Let me know if you want to follow this approach or need any kind of help regarding this.

Comment: here using radio button so only one select option for each section. not mutiple, if one radio button selected, click the another radio button means first button automatically deselect, clicked button will be selected.. each button have select and deselect option. how is possible.