# UIButton state changing while scrolling the tableview with multiple sections - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have multiple sections in my tableview with multiple custom cells(cell with radio button, cell with check box and cell with textfield). Problem is under section with radio button, only one radio button should be selectable under radio button section. After selecting, I have tried scrolling, multiple radio buttons are selected. Help much appreciated.

```
class RedioButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

var radioButtonDelegate: RedioCellDelegate?
  var cellindexPath : IndexPath?
@IBOutlet weak var btnRediouttion: UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
}
```

Cell for row method:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if ((qaArray[indexPath.section]["Que"] as! [String:String])["type"]!) == CONTROL
    {
        let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedioButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! RedioButtonCell

     cell.btnRediouttion?.tag = Int("\(indexPath.section)" +  "\(indexPath.row)")!

        cell.lblTitle!.text = String(describing: ansDetailArray[indexPath.row]["survey_answer"]!)


let deselectedImage = UIImage(named:         "Radio_Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "radio_Selected")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    btnRediouttion?.setImage(deselectedImage, for: .normal)
    btnRediouttion?.setImage(selectedImage, for: .selected)
    btnRediouttion?.addTarget(self, action:    #selector(self.radioButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

         cell.cellindexPath = indexPath;
        return cell
    }
}
func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {
    print("radio button tapped")
    let isSelected = !(radioButton?.isSelected)!
    radioButton?.isSelected = isSelected
    if isSelected {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The tableView cells are reused ( happens when scrolling ) , so you need to keep track of the selected one by saving it's `IndexPath` and assign it inside `cellForRowAt`

//

declare this in your VC

```
 var currentIndex:IndexPath?
```

//

```
class RadioButton:UIButton {

  var indexPath:IndexPath
}
```

//

```
func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: RadioButton) {

    self.currentIndex = radioButton.indexPath
}
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      if indexPath == currentIndex {
         // this should be selected
      }
      else {
         // Deselect this 
      }

      cell.radioButton.indexPath = indexPath 
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample?

Comment: radio button rows  are under section.

Comment: You can also use the tag property in the place of indexpath in above answer.

Comment: @shubham it needs processing the row & section again from the string , yes it's another alternative

Comment: You can store it in a global variable and also use variable when you are setting a tag for button. Then no extra processing occur

Comment: this is the way I am proceding, can you drop an answer for my question as well ?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/65262486/11982371